# Set Google Inbox as default e-mail client in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gmail

Is there a way to set Google Inbox as the default e-mail client in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the strange double-diamond icon in chrome browser.

http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht

Comment: Unlike in Gmail, the double-diamond icon doesn't show up in Inbox for me.